# Navigation to another page using swipe gesture (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I've searched quite a lot on the Internet but haven't been able to found the exact thing that I want.
I now that I should be using the Manipulation events such as Manipulation Started, Delta, Completed.
As I said I managed to navigate to another page using swipe combining these three events, but what I actually want is to see THE MOTION when moving from the actual page to another like for example when you swipe from the Official Windows Phone 8 page to the Apps page using a left swipe. Can you please point out on how to achieve such a thing.

http://agilemobility.net/2014/07/windows-phone-8-swipe-gesture/

This page shows an example on how to that, but the motion of moving the current page and bringing the second one is displayed.

Comment: you are talking about a pivot control

Comment: Could you give an example (link perhaps), some reference

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941103(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware of the following, and yes, **Pivot** is the answer to my question.

Taken from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941103(v=vs.105).aspx

- You can use a custom template named Windows Phone Pivot App when creating a new project. This template will come pre-populated with content and you can modify the template accordingly.
- List itemThe Pivot control can be added to the Toolbox in Visual Studio and can be easily dropped into your project.
- You can add a Windows Phone Pivot Page to an existing project.